# Restreaming raw data to ffserver gives rc buffer overflow error

Tags: ffmpeg, ffserver

My goal here is to fetch stream from live url to opencv python, process this stream and restream it to ffserver.
Below is the command i use:
*

> python store.py | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size
>   544x576  -framerate 25 -i - http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm

*
Below is my **ffserver.conf** file

```
<Feed feed1.ffm>

File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 3G
ACL allow 127.0.0.1

</Feed>

<Stream test1.mpg>
Format mpeg
VideoBitRate 128
VideoBufferSize 60000
VideoFrameRate 25
VideoSize 544x576
VideoGopSize 12
NoAudio
VideoQMax 45
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255

</Stream>
```

and when i run the command stated above it gives me the error

> **[mpeg1video @ 0x1c6e6c0] rc buffer underflow**

and to test my feed when i hit the command

> ffplay http://localhost:8090/test1.mpg

I can see the output feed being played but there is a green mask applied on the feed.Attaching Image:

[image: green mask applied over the restream]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use option -f with video4linux2 and keep -f rawvideo too.

Try:

```
 python store.py | ffmpeg -f v4l2 -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 544x576 -framerate 25 -i - http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

this will fix it.